# Notify compose of successfully pinning a widget to home screen from the app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver

I am currently trying to change the compose layout after the user is prompted and has added to home screen a widget from the launcher prompt using `requestPinAppWidget` ([doc here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent))). I know the success callback is sent after the user tapped "Add to Home screen" and it was successfull.

[image]

Here is my current code for the receiver, it works as intended, detecting when the user clicked on the "Add to Home screeen" button, but I cannot figure it out how to update the compose layout.

```
open class WidgetPinnedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {

        fun getPendingIntent(context: Context): PendingIntent {
            val callbackIntent = Intent(context, WidgetPinnedReceiver::class.java)
            callbackIntent.action = "widgetPinned"
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 1)
            callbackIntent.putExtras(bundle)
            return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                0,
                callbackIntent,
                PendingIntentUtils.defaultFlags or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (context == null || intent == null) {
            return
        }

        val widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
        if (widgetId == -1) {
            // fail
            return
        } else {
            // success        
        }
    }
}
```

How can I notify the compose layout that the widget was added successfully and then update it?

I have tried using a Disposable Effect similar to what the doc has [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#case-study-broadcastreceivers) but that didn't work.